# Ansible - give each node context to split data

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I'm using ansible over AWS-EC2 to spawn `N` number of instances each being connected to a volume containing all the data to process, that is `p` files.

I'm trying to find a way to pass some environment variables to each node so that each one can process a split of the p files.

For example, I thought I could give the total number of nodes and the number of the current node `i` so that to processing script could take the `i`th split, but I can't find a way in ansible to do such a thing.

I tried using `facts` combined with `with_indexed_items` in this manner:

```
  - name: Launch the calculation
    shell: /opt/anaconda/bin/python tests/dicho.py chdir=/root/project/
    async: 10000
    poll: 10
    environment:
      PARTIAL_DATA_SPLITS: {{ groups.antmachines|length}}
      PARTIAL_DATA_ALLOC: {{item.0}}
    with_indexed_items: groups.antmachines
```

but the loop is done one time for each node.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've answered similar question recently: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38415937/2795592

Answer (score 0):

Following Konstantin Suvorov advice, the following code does the trick:

```
  - set_fact:
      padded_host_index: "{{ play_hosts.index(inventory_hostname) }}"

  - name: Launch the calculation
    shell: /opt/anaconda/bin/python tests/dicho.py chdir=/root/project/
    async: 10000
    poll: 10
    environment:
      PARTIAL_DATA_SPLITS: {{ groups.antmachines|length }}
      PARTIAL_DATA_ALLOC: {{ padded_host_index }}
```

Comment: In your particular case `set_fact` is unnecessary because you don't need any index postporcessing – you can use `play_hosts.index(inventory_hostname)` directly to set `PARTIAL_DATA_ALLOC`. Another thought is that you should unify `play_hosts` and `groups.antmachines` – because there may be a chance that this groups will differ (e.g. you run a playbook with a limited set of hosts) and not every split will be processed.